# Why use lock mode page on a table

Tags: database, locking, deadlock, informix

I was wondering why I would need to use lock mode page on a table.

Recently I came up to a pretty good case of why not. While I was trying to insert a row on a table I got a deadlock. After lots of investigation I figured out the the lock level of my table was Page and this was the actual reason that lead to the deadlock.

My guess is that this is a common scenario on large scale high performance environments with multiple applications hitting the same db

The only thing I found is that I should use page locking if I am processing rows in the same order as the paging occurs. This looks like a weak condition that can seldom be met (especially for scaling which could render this case obsolete).

I can see why one would lock a full table or use per row locking but the Page locking does not make much sense. Or does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never *need* to use LOCK MODE PAGE on a table, but you may choose to do so.

It does no damage whatsoever if only a single row fits on a page (or a single row requires more than one page).

If you can fit multiple rows on a page, though, you have a meaningful choice between LOCK MODE PAGE and LOCK MODE ROW.  Clearly, if you use LOCK MODE ROW, then the fact that one process has a lock on one row of a page won't prevent another process from gaining a lock on a different row on the same page, whereas LOCK MODE PAGE will prevent that.

The advantage of LOCK MODE PAGE is that it requires less locks when a single process updates multiple rows on a page in a single transaction.

So, you have to do a balancing act.  You can take the view that there are so many rows in the database that the chances of two processes needing to lock different rows on the same page is negligible, and use LOCK MODE PAGE knowing that there's a small risk that you'll have processes blocking other processes that would not be blocked if you used LOCK MODE ROW.  Alternatively, you can take the view that the risk of such blocking is unacceptable and the increased number of locks is not a problem, and decide to use LOCK MODE ROW anyway.

Historically, when the number of locks was a problem because memory was scarce (in the days when big machines had less than a 100 MiB of main memory!), saving locks by using LOCK MODE PAGE made more sense than it does now when systems have multiple gigabytes of main memory.

Note that it doesn't matter which lock mode you use if two processes want to update the same row; one will get a lock and block the other until the transaction commits (or until the statement completes if you aren't using explicit transactions).

Note that the default lock mode is still LOCK MODE PAGE, mainly in deference to history where that has always been the case.  However, there is an ONCONFIG parameter, DEF_TABLE_LOCKMODE, that you can set to `row` (instead of `page`) that will set the default table lock mode to LOCK MODE ROW.  You can still override that explicitly in a DDL statement, but if you don't specify an explicit lock mode, the default will be `row` or `page` depending on the setting of DEF_TABLE_LOCKMODE.